# Python MySQL insert with list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to insert data into MySQL with a list using Python.
The list contains both strings and integers.
I am not able to use %s for string replacement also % does not work.

```
def insert(self,data):
    db =  MySQLdb.connect(db=self.database,host=self.host,port=self.port,user=self.user,passwd=self.password)
    c=db.cursor()
    var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(data))
    query = 'INSERT INTO wmr200 (time, temp_in, temp_out, dewpoint, hum_in, hum_out, windspeed, wind_direction, windchill, rain_1h, rain_24h, rain_total, rel_pressure, abs_pressure, tendency, forecast) VALUES (now(), %s);' % var_string
    c.execute(query, data)
```

error is:

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression that produces the exception:

```
query % db.literal(args)
```

requires `query` to contain one format string -- such as `%s` -- per each element of `db.literal(args)`.

Yet the value of `query` as produced by your function contains exactly zero format strings.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, i need to add 15 %s to my query string?

Comment: I added this:  
`query = 'INSERT INTO wmr200 (time, temp_in, temp_out, dewpoint, hum_in, hum_out, windspeed, wind_direction, windchill, rain_1h, rain_24h, rain_total, rel_pressure, abs_pressure, tendency, forecast) VALUES (now(), %s, %s ,%s ,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ,%s, %s, %s, %s);' % var_string`  
  
Now i get:  
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: @HyperDevil: in your example code, you can omit `data` altogether from the `execute` call since you're actually inserting the values into your query string with string formatting. However, this is probably a *HORRIBLE* idea since this is the best way to create SQL injection vulnerabilities. Lose the string formatting and `var_string` and do use the 15 `%s`s

Comment: I used this `(now(), %s, %s ,%s ,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ,%s, %s, %s, %s);' % data` it is still complainting: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string